# Google App Engine Instance Hours

Tags: google-app-engine

If I set my GAE instance hour settings to automatically scale down to the minimum number of idle instances, does this mean that when the first instance cannot handle the requests, a second will spin up, then when the overflow requests are handled and the second instance is shut down, I will still be charged the full 15 minutes for an instance start up? Then if it starts up again within the 15 minutes will I be charged for another start up?

Answer (score 0):

According to Google's document on instance hours billing (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Instance_Billing), Whenever you instance is up you will pay for it, and you will pay for "shutdown" until 15 minutes later.  If you start another instance during that 15 miunutes, you should not be charged, because you're still charged for the "first" 15 minutes.

That is all conjecture though... I could be totally wrong in my assumption